# Vue.js modify computed property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am trying to modify a `moment.js` instance that resides in `vue.js` computed property like so.

```
computed: {
    currentDate() {
        return moment();
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to call it with a method like this one, nothing happens:

```
methods: {
    prevMonth() {
        this.currentDate = moment(this.currentDate).subtract(1, 'months');
    }
}
```

I am guessing this is because computed properties only allow to act as getters(and optionally setters). How can I change this behavior though?

I oversimplified the example since I am using the cmoputed property to fetch data from my `vuex` store. I am no longer able to manipulate it though.

Is there some way I can populate a local `currentDate` property with the `vuex` store's value so I can still manipulate it and add months, etc?

I have though about using the `mounted` property for this but I only mount my component once. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `currentDate` property belongs to your Vuex store, you shouldn't be manipulating it inside your components. You should instead: 1) map the getter locally as a computed property and 2) map the mutation locally as a method.

Here's an example of what your `date` Vuex module might look like:

```
export default {
    state: {
        currentDate: moment()
    },
    mutations: {
        subtractMonth (state, date) {
            state.currentDate = moment(state.currentDate).subtract(1, 'months');
        }
    },
    getters: {
        getCurrentDate: (state) => {
            return state.currentDate
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how the component would make use of it, without actually doing anything "locally":

```
import { mapGetters, mapMutations } from 'vuex'
export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({
            currentDate: 'getCurrentDate'
        })
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapMutations({
            prevMonth: 'subtractMonth'
        })
    }
}
```

You'd still be able to bind `currentDate` inside your component and call `prevMonth` as before, but now everything is being done via the Vuex single state.

Comment: You are not able to mutate the currentDate property without committing mutations though. It would mean I would have to move all my local(simple) methods that manipulate the `moment()` instance into my store as mutations. I do not feel that this would be justified.

Comment: Mapping mutations means that `this.prevMonth()` is actually `this.$store.commit('subtractMonth')`, so you _are_ commiting a mutation every time you call the method. If you're `moment` instance is in the Vuex state, you can only manipulate it by mutating the state. If it's not, then there's something missing on your question without which we cannot provide the ideal answer.

Answer (score 1):

Computed properties are not methods, that you can call. If you want to have such method, move `currentDate` to methods. The you also can invoke it from `mounted`.

Comment: It will no longer be a property instance in that case and will not be part of the local state. I need the property `currentDate` to default to `moment()` when it is not existent in the `vuex` store or take that `vuex` store value with it is set.

Comment: Ok, I would suggest to modify the question, so that you explain exactly what do you want to achieve. I have a feeling, that you reached some dead end, and what you want to achieve can be achieved in simpler way.

Comment: Sorry, it is really hard to explain since I am pretty far in and I am trying to oversimplify this. I has been solved though. I pretty much needed to copy `vuex` state to local component state. I have used `created()` to do this. I need to copy the vuex state otherwise it couldn't be manipulated. Thanks for your help though.